# MIPS operand of incorrect type error. Loading data into register

Tags: load, mips, cpu-word, operand

MIPS operand of incorrect type error. Loading data into register

```
.data
    myMessage: .word 2
    myMessage2: .word 24
.text
    add $t0, $zero, myMessage 
    add $t1, $zero, myMessage2
```

why does it say incorrect type? I thought since myMessage is an integer it would be okay... (First time using MIPS)

Answer (score 1):

Technically `myMessage` is *the address of* the location in memory where the word 2 is located.

MIPS uses a load/store-architecture, meaning that if you want to use some data in memory as an operand you should load it into a register first:

```
la $a0, myMessage   # Get the address
lw $t0, ($a0)       # Get the value at that address
```

You might be able to get away with writing `lw $t0, myMessage`, if the assembler can take care of transforming that into the correct instruction sequence for you.